# How to apply XSLT transformation in LiveCycle form

Tags: livecycle

I have a LiveCycle form where I am embedding a sample XML.
I want to know hoe to map the field values to the sample XML so that when the user clicks on the submit as XML button the submitted XML should carry the values bound within the form field tags.

Thanks.

Bibhu.

Comment: This is not an XSLT question, retagged.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `bind` tag within each `field` object in your form to point to your sample xml data. LiveCycle Designer can do this for you (data panel->new data connection->sample xml->drag and drop xml objects to your form fields).